# kSOAP2 - Connection issues in Android on a GPRS network

Tags: android, android-ksoap2, android-internet

I've been using the ksoap2-android library in a lot of my projects to use SOAP webservices. Why? Because I don't know any alternatives (maybe there aren't any).

My problem? Their reliability on a GPRS/EDGE network (no 3G/4G where I live).

Here is the code I usually use:

```
public String Login()
    {
        String status = "";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
                SOAP_LOGIN_METHOD);

        request.addProperty("strUserName", Login.uName);
        request.addProperty("strPassword", Login.pass);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        Log.d("Login Request: ", "" + request.toString());

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

        try
        {
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_LOGIN_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            status = response.getProperty("LoginResult").toString();

            Log.d("Login Status: ", ""
                    + response.getProperty("LoginResult").toString());
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.d("Login Service Exception", exception.toString());
            status = "-1";
        }

        return status;
    }
```

Now on a wifi network, this works mostly fine, but whenever I try the same via GPRS/EDGE, most of the service calls return a TIMEOUT or CONNECTION error.

I know the problem lies partly with the network as well, but at times for instance a Viber call is working fine (with a little packet drop here and there) but a webservice fails.

**My question? Is there any way to increase the reliability of SOAP services on Android over a GPRS network?**

I looked at the kSOAP2-android documentation to see if there was anything that might help, for instance, if the HTTP request fails once, and returns something we can use, we can but it in a loop to keep trying till it succeeds, but the return types are mostly void.